# Secondary selection list filtered by Primary selection list

Tags: excel, list, validation, filter

I got to sheets, first one include ID and hospital names, second sheet have ID (hospital dependency) and ward name.

By data validation list I got already the primary list, now I'm looking for the way how I can filter the secondary selection list showing just the wards that have same ID like the hospital.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Note: is not an option for me to create Names because I have something llike 500 hospitals so I can not really create and manage such number of names.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can handle it with this. I designed a Simple Excel. My Sheet 1 is called "LIST OF HOSPITALS" and it contains ID and Name of hospitals.
[image]

My Sheet 2, called "LIST OF WARDENS" is the list of all wardens in all hospitals, related by then ID of hospital.
[image]

Also, **I created only 1 named range**, called "My_Wardens", because we need a dinamic range to be the source of our data validation list for Wardens. You say creating names is not an option, but we'll create just 1 name and it will be always the same name and with VBA code we'll change sourcedata of the name. That's the trick.

[image]

Now, in Sheet 1 in cell E11 is my first Data validation List. It just shows the hospital ID. Cell E12 is the important one, because it has the data validation list with the wardens related to hospital id selected.

My code is this one. It will trigger only if you change the value of Cell E11. Adapt the code to your needs.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address(False, False, xlA1) <> "E11" Then Exit Sub 'E11 must be replaced with cell reference where your wardens data validation list appears

Dim MyWardens() As String
Dim Wardens As String
Dim i As Long
Dim HospitalCell As Range

Set HospitalCell = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LIST OF HOSPITALS").Range(Target.Address) 'Cell Reference where your hospital validation list appears.


i = 2
Wardens = ""

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LIST OF WARDENS") 'Sheet name of where the list of wardens is. In my example, data starts at row 1 and Column A is Hospital ID
                                           'and columnb B is Warden name
    Do Until .Cells(i, 1).Value = ""

        If HospitalCell.Value = .Cells(i, 1).Value Then 'We save just the row reference, because we know the column of Wardens.
            If Len(Wardens) = 0 Then
                Wardens = i
            Else
                Wardens = Wardens & "||" & i
            End If
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop

End With



MyWardens = Split(Wardens, "||")

'We just need first row (it's in Lbound) and last row (It's in Ubound) so we use R1C1 notation, because we know column of Wardens
Wardens = "='LIST OF WARDENS'!R" & MyWardens(0) & "C2:R" & MyWardens(UBound(MyWardens)) & "C2"

ThisWorkbook.Names("My_wardens").RefersToR1C1 = Wardens


End Sub
```

Now, If I select, for example, Hospital 2, Cell E12 wil show just Wardens related to that hospital.
[image]

Same happens if I select, for example, Hospital 5.

[image]

Adapt the code to your needs. Hope this helps!

Comment: It looks great! This is what I was looking for, only difference is that I will have the validation cell in other sheet call "Form" in cell U2, should I indicate it some how or just change E11 by U2? I dont thinl so could you guide me on that? Other question I got is, should I include the headers on name range? Thanks!

Comment: Should I as well indicate that Available wards are in the other sheet (Form) on cell N3?

Comment: You must change sheets references and range References, so yeah, E11 should be replaced by U2. Also, change the sheet names of my example by your sheet names. Test it and don't give up, you will get it. IF this answer helped you, mark it as correct. If you cannot adapt the code to your needs in a few days, just open a new question with the code and your data and probably another SO member will help.

Comment: Still don’t get it, I should be doing something wrong. What I have by now is: One sheet call "Form" there I got one validation selection list looking at range in "Hospitals" sheet, column B where hospital names are. Then in cell U2 in "Form" sheet I did a Vlookup to get the Hospital ID, so it should be the target cell. Still on same sheet, on cell N3, I place a validation selection list looking at "Wards" sheet range column B where I got the ward names

Comment: As you indicated I create the name "My_Wards" that includes columns A & B on "Wards" sheet (Including the headers). Conclusions, Selection list for Hospitals works and by Vlookup I extract the Hospital ID but on second selection list I still have all registers. I modify a little bit your code to match with cells and sheet names, but not fully sure if I did it right or if I'm forgetting something.

Comment: Macro looks now like this:

Comment: No headers, and use Hospital ID, not names. Make sure your list of wardens is ordered by hospital ID. Just try to organise the data as i posted in the example

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address(False, False, xlA1) <> "U2" Then Exit Sub 'U2 must be 
replaced with cell reference where your wardens data validation list appears
'This cell (U2) is on sheet "Form" not sure how to indicate it


Dim MyWardens() As String
Dim Wards As String
Dim i As Long
Dim HospitalCell As Range

Set HospitalCell = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hospitals").Range(Target.Address) 
'Cell Reference where your hospital validation list appears.


i = 2
Wards = ""

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Wards") 'Sheet name of where the list of wards is. 
In my example, data starts at row 1 and Column A is Hospital ID
                                       'and columnb B is Ward name
Do Until .Cells(i, 1).Value = ""

    If HospitalCell.Value = .Cells(i, 1).Value Then 'We save just the row reference, because we know the column of Wardens.
        If Len(Wards) = 0 Then
            Wards = i
        Else
            Wards = Wards & "||" & i
        End If
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop

End With



MyWardens = Split(Wards, "||")

'We just need first row (it's in Lbound) and last row (It's in Ubound) so we 
use R1C1 notation, because we know column of Wardens
Wards = "='Wards'!R" & MyWardens(0) & "N3:R" & MyWardens(UBound(MyWardens)) & "N3"

ThisWorkbook.Names("My_wards").RefersToR1C1 = Wards

End sub
```

Comment: Make sure you post this code in the Event `Worksheet_Change` Of your Sheet "Form".

Comment: Maybe this is the key. How should I do that?

Comment: I have right now the code on same place as other macros, is it the correct place?

Comment: post this code in the Event Worksheet_Change Of your Sheet "Form"

Comment: I open the VBA editor, select the sheet form and copy the code there, is it correct?

Comment: Hi I just add some pictures in order to clarify it hoping it will helps you to help me, :)

Comment: If you have 0 idea of VBa and if you have 0 Idea of Excel, I'm afraid you will have to hire a developer, because we cannot be here posting thousands of comments with all steps to do this. Learn some Basics from Excel and VBA and the code I posted will work for you.

Comment: I have idea but I'm not expertise, this is why I ask to the expertises, sorry if disturbing. I would said it is almost done but I'm doing a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Step by step is goin.. now I have error on this line: Wards = "='Wards'!R" & MyWardens(0) & "N3:R" & MyWardens(UBound(MyWardens)) & "N3"

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Sorry I'm not so good in Excel, :), I hope it is like this?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is the sheet for Hospitals

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is the sheet Form wher I have the two selection lists

Answer (score 0):

[image]

And this is the Wards sheet and for the name My_wards